# Django Model Design - Many-To-Many Fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Coming from a php background, I know how I would do this 'by hand' but I can't seem to get my head round how to structure my database with Django ORM.

The app centres around a checklist. A Checklist has some identifying features, lets say `Name`, `DateOfBirth` and `ChecklistType`

There are several `ChecklistType`s, each of which has many `ChecklistOption`s. A `ChecklistOption` may or may not be in several `ChecklistType`s

My initial thought was to create a model for `ChecklistType` and `ChecklistTypeOptions` to store the 'configuration' of the Checklists, and a seperate model for `Checklist` and `Requirements` (respectively) to link to the `Customer` model. I thought I would manually look up the configuration and create the latter model entries in the view that creates the `Customer`. I then realised this defeats to point of the ORM!

I'm sure that this question could be solved by a proper understanding of the way to use Many-to-many fields in the models, but the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) seems to only deal with simple applications of this. If I create a ManyTomany field in the `Checklist` to `ChecklistOption` (with `ChecklistType` as a ChoiceField), I lose the ability to specify which options are applicable to that type.

I'm sure this type of thing must be done regularly, but I can't get my head around it.

Thanks in advance,

### Clarification - Example Data

#### ChecklistOptions

```
Cheese {boolean}
Tomato {boolean}
Bacon {boolean}
Chicken {boolean}
Coffee {boolean}
Pepperoni {boolean}
Salami {boolean}
Mushrooms {boolean}
Eggs {boolean}
```

#### ChecklistTypes

```
ThingsToPutOnPizza: {options: Cheese, Tomato, Bacon, Chicken, Salami, Mushrooms}
ThingsToEatAtBreakfast: {options: Cheese, Bacon, Coffee, Eggs}
```

#### Customer

```
John Smith: {Name: "John Smith", DOB: 1984-12-17, Checklist: ThingsToEatAtBreakfast}
Jane Jones: {Name: "Jane Jones", DOB: 1987-07-22, Checklist: ThingsToPutOnPizza}
Frank Allen {Name: "Frank Allen", DOB: 1990-04-01, Checklist: ThingsToPutOnPizza}
```

### Workflow

A user creates a customer, and selects the checklist type. Another user has to 'complete' the checklist, so selects the customer from list and is presented with a list of checkboxes for the options in that checklist type, and of those options they may tick some and not others. On saving the form/model their user and the time is logged against the checklist to mark it as complete.

Comment: Why would you "lose the ability to specify which options are applicable to that type" ? i dont think that is true.

Comment: Then how do I specify that a given `ChecklistOption` only appears for certain `ChecklistTypes`?

Comment: you mean in the form?

Comment: Both the form and the data. I assumed if you get it right at the model level the forms take care of themselves?

Comment: no, just create you models as you initially suggested.  For the form you can create custom queries using for example ModelChoiceField .

Comment: Can you you give some more concrete examples of what can/will the `options` be and what kind of `types` there will be? This will help me suggest a proper model structure. However, with the model structure you suggested, right now each `checklist` has only one `set` of options chosed based on the `type`, what's the problem with that? Ohh I think I just get it, you want each checklist to have only a `subset` of options based on their `type`, not all the options in that `type` is that right?

Comment: @Todor Example data & workflow added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тhis is probably the simplest solution:

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class CheckList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    checklist_type = models.ForeignKey('CheckListType')
    options = models.ManyToManyField('CheckListOption', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class CheckListType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    options = models.ManyToManyField('CheckListOption')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class CheckListOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import CheckList, CheckListOption

class CheckListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CheckList
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CheckListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['options'].queryset = CheckListOption.objects.filter(
                checklisttype=self.instance.checklist_type_id
            )
        else:
            self.fields['options'].queryset = CheckListOption.objects.none()
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .forms import CheckListForm
from .models import CheckList, CheckListType, CheckListOption

class CheckListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CheckListForm

admin.site.register(CheckList, CheckListAdmin)
admin.site.register(CheckListType)
admin.site.register(CheckListOption)
```

There is only one drawback - when you already have a saved `CheckList` instance and you want to change the `checklist_type`, you wont get the new `options` on the moment. The user doing the change should unselect the selected options (*this is kind of an optional, but if not done, the selected options will remain until the next save*), save the model and edit it again to chose the new options.

Comment: Would this work with django internationalization/localization? If not, what changes would be needed to make it work?

Comment: No reason to not to.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the basic requirements:

> The app centres around a checklist. A `Checklist`has some identifying
>   features, lets say `Name`, `DateOfBirth` and `ChecklistType`
>
> There are several `ChecklistType`s, each of which has many
>   `ChecklistOption`s. A `ChecklistOption` may or may not be in several
>   `ChecklistType`s

The below models take care of your initial requirements:

```
class CheckListOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CheckListType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(CheckListOption)

class Checklist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.DateField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(CheckListType)
```

Now, with those in mind; lets see how you plan to use these models:

> A user creates a customer, and selects the checklist type. Another
>   user has to 'complete' the checklist, so selects the customer from
>   list and is presented with a list of checkboxes for the options in
>   that checklist type, and of those options they may tick some and not
>   others. On saving the form/model their user and the time is logged
>   against the checklist to mark it as complete.

To take care of your tracking, you need to add a few more fields to the `Checklist` model:

```
class Checklist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.DateField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(CheckListType)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, name='creator')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                     name='maker', blank=True, null=True)
    completed_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def is_complete(self):
        return self.completed_on
```

To take care of your requirement that *"and of those options they may tick some and not others"*, you'll need to modify the `CheckListType` model, by creating a custom [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships); which will allow you specify options on a relationship:

```
class CheckListOptionConfig(models.Model):
    checklisttype = models.ForeignKey('CheckListType')
    optiontype = models.ForeignKey('CheckListOption')
    is_required = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class CheckListType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(CheckListOption, through='CheckListOptionConfig')
```

The rest of your workflow describes the user interface; which can easily be configured to show all manners of alerts/warnings if the right options are not ticked.

Comment: So with this 4 model structure, how do I configure each `ChecklistType`? When I load this structure and create admin tables I can create a checklist (selecting a `ChecklistType`) but I don't see how the actual options are configured or populated - I can create `ChecklistTypes`, `ChecklistOptions` and in the `ChecklistOptionConfig` I can link those together, but not how to link `ChecklistOptions` to `Checklist`?

Comment: I think your issue is not the model itself, but how to show a selection of the fields.  You need something like  Checklist.objects.filter(options=checklistoption) .  btw, is it just for the admin?